# PHP regex slug with at least 1 letter, but not all numeric

Tags: php, regex, expression

How to make a regular expression that match the following requirements:

- Contains at least 1 letter (a-z)
- May be contain numeric (0-9) and dash (-)

Ex:

```
dan-huyen : Match
dan-huyen-123: Match
123-dan-huyen: Match
123: Not match
```

Comment: Please show your attempts and sample code, otherwise your question is likely to be downvoted and/or closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic password validation problem. You can use this regex:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])[a-z0-9-]+$
```

See what matches on [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/fQ1iD5/17).

In PHP:

```
$theregex = '~^(?=.*[a-z])[a-z0-9-]+$~';
if (preg_match($theregex, $yourstring)) {
    // Yes! It matches!
    } 
else { // nah, no luck...
     }
```

**Explanation**

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- The lookahead `(?=.*[a-z])` asserts that we can find any chars, then one LC letter
- `[a-z0-9-]+` matches lower-case letters, digits and the dash
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: I like your solution. I've learn one more things from it. The lookahead partern is new for me.

Comment: Ah... You're going to love lookaheads! :) They have so many uses in regex.

Answer (score 1):

A regex pattern that solves your problem is:

```
/[a-z]{1,}[0-9\-]{0,}/
```

**Explanation:**

- `[a-z]{1,}` tells that at least 1 letter (lower case) is necessary on some part in the string
- `[0-9\-]{0,}` tells that the string can contais numbers or - (dash) on any part

And you can use the following function with the given regex pattern to validate your string on **php**:

```
preg_match('/[a-z]{1,}[0-9\-]{0,}/', $subject)
```

In this case, `$subject` is the variable that contains the string to be checked. More information about the funcionality of preg_match at http://php.net/preg_match. I dont explain about this because you asked only about the regex.

Comment: Thank you, LCPA. Your regex works fine! I've tested your php function and it also works as expected.